# scrollViewDidScroll: when scroll programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this delegate which intended to be execute when user scrolls with his fingers :

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

I have this line that scroll with code to the start :

```
[scroller scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0,scroller.frame.size.width,scroller.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
```

When i execute this line of code to scroll programmatically, the first delegate is also being called.
I would like to eliminate this from happen.

I was trying to set the delegate to nil, but it still execute the delegate:

```
scroller.delegate=nil;//to not excute scrolldidscroll
[scroller scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0,scroller.frame.size.width,scroller.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
scroller.delegate=self;
```

EDIT:

I have read this great answer :[Setting contentOffset programmatically triggers scrollViewDidScroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418311/setting-contentoffset-programmatically-triggers-scrollviewdidscroll) but it seems that his solution(the first) is without animation, while i need that animation .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There might be a better solution but this should work :

Declare a boolean in your .h

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) BOOL scrollingProgrammatically;
```

And in your .m :

```
self.scrollingProgrammatically = YES;
[scroller scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0,scroller.frame.size.width,scroller.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
```

...

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if(!self.scrollingProgrammatically){
        ...
    }
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    self.scrollingProgrammatically = NO;
}
```

Comment: Ok , i will go for it .. :)

Comment: hmm, yeah there is probably no lighter way to do this. Also I've edited my answer since didEndDragging is not called if scroll is called programmatically.

Comment: it actually did ! the dragging method(your first answer) did worked for me as well. strange .