# scrollViewDidScroll scrollViewWillEndDragging runs simultaneously on main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am confused with `scrollViewDidScroll` `scrollViewWillEndDragging`. Do they work as async way?

I found that at a moment, both `scrollViewDidScroll` and `scrollViewWillEndDragging` are **triggered** and **not finished**.

[image: scrollViewDidScroll stackTrack]
[image: scrollViewWillEndDragging stackTrack]

ps: **NO BLOCK** in my code

**EDIT**

I will use a *property* in `scrollViewDidScroll`, which will be updated at the end of `scrollViewWillEndDragging`. My question is whether `scrollViewDidScroll` and `scrollViewWillEndDragging` run as async way. If so I need use lock to prevent it.

Comment: What do you mean by not finished ?

Comment: breakpoints created by stacktrack don't reach the end of both scrollViewDidScroll and scrollViewWillEndDragging @Rajat

Comment: you can see the screenshot, still remain code after breakpoint

Comment: Your breakpoint is Active, you need to continue execution of your code by pressing Play.

Answer (score 0):

> scrollViewWillEndDragging

This `UIScrollViewDelegate` method will be called when user finishes scrolling the content within your `UIScrollView`.

> scrollViewDidScroll

While this `UIScrollViewDelegate`method will be called when user scrolls the content within your `UIScrollView`.

Comment: thank you, i have updated my question, hope that it will help you understand my issue...

Comment: @Tepmnthar you want to detect when user starts scrolling and when user ends scrolling ?

Comment: I want to use new value set in scrollViewWillEndDragging when scrollview still scrolling (decelerating).

Comment: check this method - https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619386-scrollviewwillbegindecelerating

Comment: Finally I found this [why-scrollViewDidScroll-triggeredl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418311/setting-contentoffset-programmatically-triggers-scrollviewdidscroll). I have edited **contentOffset** in my `scrollViewWillEndDragging` then `scrollViewDidScroll` triggered. My mistake. Sorry for not giving enough information. Any way thank you very much.