# ScrollView v Custom Transition (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiviewanimationtransition

I am making an app where you basically answer questions and then swipe left to get the next question. I like the transition of scroll views and would like to emulate that. I was wondering whether it would be recommended to create a custom transition between view controllers and or just implement a scroll view.

A scroll view seems easier, but not sure if it is possible (or if it is actually easier) when considering the following caveats.

Some caveats:
  - Can only swipe one direction (can't go back to previous questions)
  - Need to be able to load up another question from a datasource after swiping (obviously)
  - There is no set number of questions (so they could swipe forever and keep getting new questions)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After reading your requirement, the most suitable UI widget would be `UICollectionView`.

Here are some points which would help in cover up your requirement.

**1. Sizing the cell**

You might want to show the question and answer related views across the whole view, in that case your collection view will be pinned to `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` with constraint and your cell size would be equal to the collection view bound's size.

Implement the `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate`'s [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
           sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return collectionView.bounds.size
}
```

**2. Enable Paging**

Enable the paging of the collectionView, so that the scroll does not stays at any breaking (i.e scrolling stopped at between two questionary cells).

```
collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
```

**3. Locking the scroll direction (only scrolling to right)**

If you target for `iOS 11.0+` you may have a look @ `UICollectionViewDragDelegate` ([appledoc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdragdelegate)) which will provide rich set of functionality to achieve this.

Otherwise i like to suggest you to use following

```
public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

which will notify you every single scroll user doing in your `CollectionView`. It's a method from `UIScrollView` and `UICollectionView` inherit it from `UIScrollView`.

```
var lastOffsetX = -1
public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    // for the first time only
    if lastOffset < 0 {
        lastOffsetX = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        return
    }


    if lastOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.x {
        // stick to the right most position -- not enabling the user to go left
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = lastOffset
    } else {
        // take the user ahead to the right position
        lastOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    }        
}
```

While dealing this way you may face a issue that setting contentOffset inside the `scrollViewDidScroll` might end up firing up the `scrollViewDidScroll` method. If you face this you may take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418311/setting-contentoffset-programmatically-triggers-scrollviewdidscroll). Surely i didn't ran this code, but with few exemption, it should work.

Hope it helps, Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

`UIPageViewController` might be a good approach.

Always return `nil` for `viewControllerBefore` to prevent "swiping back."

Return `nil` for `viewControllerAfter` until the user has answered the current question to prevent "swiping ahead" early.