# Vertical and horizontal scrolling collection views in a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a couple horizontal scrolling collection views and one vertical scrolling collection view that are added to the same view.  These collection views are overlapping like this.

[image]

If you're touching the horizontal scrolling collection view I would still like to be able to scroll the vertical scrolling collection view and vice versa.  Is that possible to do?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918481/making-two-uiscrollviews-follow-each-others-scrolling/7918717#7918717